# Angular Animations: div enter behind another div

Tags: html, css, angular, animation

I'm trying to do a simple thing in my Angular 7 application.

Basically, I have a title and when I click on it, a comment will `ease-in` from above to place itself just below the title. The problem is, when the comment is moving, **it shows on top of the title** which is not quite the effect wanted.

I tried adding a `z-index` property on the CSS to elevate the title but to no avail.

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, transition, style, animate } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}),
        animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  visible = false;

  showMessage() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
  }
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<div (click)="showMessage()">
    <div class="title">Click here to reveal the comment</div>
    <div class="title">25/04/2019 17:30:00</div>
    <div class="comment" *ngIf="visible" [@slideInOut]>Lorem ipsum...</div>
</div>
```

> app.component.css

```
.title {
  background-color: aqua;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.comment {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w771ck) to show the problem.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to z-index work. You need to add `position: relative` or `absolute` to the element. In your case, add also `position: relative` to the .title.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following:

```
.title, .comment{
  position:relative;
}
```

`z-index` only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).

See [Fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ufeoj?file=src/app/app.component.css)